# How to whitelist html tags in Asp.net ValidationAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm using Asp.net "ValidationAttribute" to validate user input, Currently i throw error if user enters any html tags like `<html>,<h1>,<div>` etc etc but i want to whitelist few tags and do not want to throw error if user enters input with some tags like following should not fail.

```
<strong> hello world </strong>
<p>hello </p>
```

but the following should fail since it's `div` not in whitelist tags array above

```
<div>hello</div>
```

Current implementation:

```
public sealed class WhiteListAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public static bool EnableWhiteListTags { get; set; }
    private static string[] whitelistTags = new[] { "strong" };

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string str = (string)value;

        if (str != null && 
            !EnableWhiteListTags &&
            !RequestValidator.Current.InvokeIsValidRequestString(null, str, RequestValidationSource.Form, null, out int index))
        {
            return new ValidationResult($"A potentially dangerous value was detected from request {validationContext.Name}: {str}");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

How can i allow user to enter only specific html tags which i defined in my array `private static string[] whitelistTags = new[] { "strong" };`, so let's say if user enters any text which has html (`<strong>`) tag , validation should not fail but if user enters any other text with html tags like (`<div>, <p>`) etc , it should fail as it does currently

Comment: it's not clear what you want :(

Comment: sorry, not being clear, i just updated the last paragraph to be more clear :), Just an fyi, currently my function works but it fails if user enters any html tag in their input but i want to allow user to be able to use some html tags, and for that i created array where i can define html tags which user can enter

Comment: Wait....isn't it an obvious behaviour ? Just don't include the html tags that you don't want :)

Comment: Yes that's what i'm doing but the problem is in this check
!RequestValidator.Current.InvokeIsValidRequestString
it fails so i'm asking how can i whitelist some tags so this validation check does'nt fail

Comment: Firstly, i don't see where you are looping through the array...Secondly, the behaviour is normal .... i guess you should try looping through the list

Comment: Yes, You're right, i can loop through the array and replace all the allowed tags with empty string so that the validation check does'nt fail but i was looking for the out of the box functionality if there is so i dont have to hack it around...

Comment: yes...there's always a way , why don't u use `linQ` ?

Comment: I'm sorry if i sound stupid what Linq would provide in here and would allow us to ignore the validation fail if there's specific tag ?

Comment: I will post an answer in a minute :)

Answer (score 1):

I think using RegEx should be faster and more convenient than normal string operations or replacing all white-listed tags:

```
public sealed class WhiteListAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public static bool EnableWhiteListTags { get; set; }
    private static List<string> whitelistTags = new List<string>() { "strong" };
    private static Regex regex = new Regex("(</?([^>/]*)/?>)");

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string str = (string)value;

        if (str != null && 
            ((!EnableWhiteListTags &&
            !RequestValidator.Current.InvokeIsValidRequestString(null, str, RequestValidationSource.Form, null, out int index)) ||
            (EnableWhiteListTags && !AllTagsValid(str))))
        {
            return new ValidationResult($"A potentially dangerous value was detected from request {validationContext.Name}: {str}");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    private static bool AllTagsValid(string input)
    {
        var matches = regex.Matches(input);
        var tags = matches.OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[2].Value);
        return tags.All(t => whitelistTags.Contains(t.Trim()));
    }
}
```

Here I get a list of all tags via regex and then check if the tag is in the white-list. The group at `m.Groups[2]` always contains the tag name incl. all attributes but no opening or closing `<`, `>` or `/`. See [HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ChrqcD) for a short example.

Comment: This doesn't work for this kind of strings 

<a href='www.google.com'>www.google.com</a>

and whitelisting a element

Answer (score 0):

Just use `LINQ` to loop through the list :

```
  bool contains = list.Any(x => mystring.Contains(x));

  if (contains == true)
   {
     ////codes here 

   }
   else
    {
     ////if not in list
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting using LINQ, but it looks to me i was not able to clarify my requirement. The issue is not looping over the array, issue is how to whitelist the specific tags, so if i use your logic it would only succeed if input contains the tags from array but as i said earlier it would not work(which is wrong) when input contains plain text.

Comment: @zubairm , I really don't get it ...... what do you mean by plain text here ?? If input contains string that exists in list , my code will check it ...what's wrong with it ?

Comment: stupid me, let me try to explain again :(
validator should only pass if input is : 
"hello world" or  "<strong>hello world</strong>", so if i use your check it would only pass when input contains list item but not if it does'nt contain any list item , like for this input "hello world" ??

Comment: and even if it passes the validator check would still fail??
!RequestValidator.Current.InvokeIsValidRequestString(null, str, RequestValidationSource.Form, null, out int index))

Comment: @zubairm , re-check my code and mark it as the answer please :)

Comment: Thanks for helping in understanding LINQ

Comment: No unfortunately :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169284/discussion-between-zubairm-and-zack-raiyan).